# html5 problem capturing camera snapshot on android smartphone

Tags: html, android-camera

I am having a problem with html5 related to managing the camera on an android smartphone.

The program flow is:

- the user clicks on a button and the smartphone camera is opened
- the user takes a snapshot from the camera
- the camera snapshot must be sent to an external endpoint (base64 encoded)

I observe that the snapshot is not sent to the external endpoint (or is sent empty)

With the following code:

```
<input type="file" name="back" ref={ref1} style={{ display: "none", }} onChange={handleAddImages} accept="image/*" capture />
```

The smartphone opens the camera correctly, but when the camera is closed then the snapshot content is lost.

I am guessing that maybe the browser is reloading the page or maybe the memory is cleared.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.